# C and C++ Tagging

Tags: discussion, tags

This is one of my pet peeves, a vast majority of posts are tagged with C and C++ initially whereas it should have been C or C++.

Quite a few of these posts are quickly edited and tagged correctly, but makes me wonder if the tags should be exclusive, if we even have that capability?

Comment: There are many questions that are legitimately C and C++. So no, they aren't exclusive.

Comment: There's a related issue of C++/CLI guys thinking they write in C++.

Comment: Conceptually tho, how can a question be about in both languages?

Comment: In general I agree with the suggestion.  There are very few examples that fall into the intersection of C and C++ where the C++ tag is required.  C brings only a few features to the table that C++ doesn't offer (VLA's come to mind); most C code will compile with little modification with a C++ compiler.  Just the C tag might be sufficient for these cases.

Comment: @Casper: Examples provided in the preexisting question I linked.  I wanted to vote to close as dupe, but the other is now migrated to SE meta, so we should keep this as a pointer to it.

Comment: Definite duplicate of the migrated question.

Comment: There is a subset of C++ that is extremely close to C, so there are questions that can be tagged as both. Note that in K&R for ANSI C89, all code examples compile in C++ as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they should not be mutually exclusive.

Already discussed as [Disallow the tagging of questions with both C and C++ tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74538/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags), consensus was reached.